# Great way to perform continious integration with Angular CLI and Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, angular-cli

I trying to configure a correct way to perform a continious integration with Angular CLI.

Just for fun, I manage my Jenkins in Windows and I have created a test project with Angular CLI.

This project is bound to Bitbucket remote and I using Sourcetree as version control system.

But I have multiple questions about the correct workflow to apply because i'm pretty confused.

**1)** Angular CLI allow us to build a project with command `ng build`. It create a folder named `dist`. Ok, but this folder is ignored in `.gitignore`, why ?
I mean, I need this folder because this is used by my Jenkins job for deploy it across FTP in my domain, no ? If the folder is ignored, it will not be available in remote bitbucket, so unusable by Jenkins.

**2)** Jenkins is used to perform some tasks for the deployment. It shouldn't be used to do the same thing like `ng build` ? In my mind, the concat, minification, etc... should be integrate in the job task, do I 'm right ? According this with split the "build" task ?

I need some clarification. This is the first time that I'm doing this.

Thank's you.

Comment: Nobody can advance me ?

Answer (score 3):

1) It is really not the best practice to have the `dist` folder under source control. The `dist` folder contains an output of your `ng build`, meaning every time you run `ng build`, contents of the `dist` folder change. If you happened to have it under source control it would lead to merge conflicts on regular basis. It is a purpose of a build (any build) to generate this folder. Your CI job is also a build, so it also produces the `dist` folder.
Jenkins in particular has a separate 'workspace' for every job you configure. On initiation of your CI job an update of the workspace is performed (depending on your configuration and VCS used). Then the fresh sources are used to run a build, as you would on your local machine. `ng build` cleans the `dist` folder and creates a new one.
By the time the build will have finished, you are ready to deploy the dist folder in any way you deem fit (zip it -> send it over FTP/SSH -> inflate -> perform the necessary tasks to have the things served through your HTTP server).

2) The concatenation, minification and bundling should be performed by your CI job indeed. Thankfully, `ng cli` is able to do all that for you. Run `ng build --prod`. The `--prod` switch will enable bundle minification and AOT compilation, generating the smallest possible bundles for your distribution.
A good idea is to add a step to gzip your .css and .js files and configure your HTTP server to serve the gzipped versions of the bundles, if asked (`Accept-Encoding: gzip`).
For a windows machine, this will do the job:
`cd dist
FOR %%i IN (*.js) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe" a "%%~ni.js.gz" "%%i"
FOR %%i IN (*.css) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7za.exe" a "%%~ni.css.gz" "%%i"`

As mentioned in @burcakulug's answer, if you have an artifact management system in place you should consider setting up a Jenkins job pipeline. One job to build, bundle and archive your project, a second (downstream) job to deploy.

Hope this helps a little :).

Answer (score 0):

1. the build artifacts, generated code, compiled classes...etc. are **NOT** source controlled as a best practice. the source code is your source of truth, so anything you can build/preprocess from there is ignored from source control. typically, your the jobs in your build pipeline package your application/artifacts and deploy it some repository for future use or delivery, or archive via Jenkins.
2. in Jenkins, you can specify downstream jobs that can be manually or automatically triggered depending on the configuration. I personally prefer to have a base initial build job that gets triggered by SCM via a service hook when there is a push, which builds the artifacts/app first, and also archive the build artifacts to an artifact repository. you can have a downstream delivery job that can do the deployment of the build artifacts and here you can utilize several Jenkins plugins for the deployment depending on your use case. By the way, once you setup upstream/downstream relations in the build jobs, you can create a pipeline view by selecting the initial job. it creates a nice view of the pipeline.

I recommend you to also take a look at [Jenkis downstream job fails to find upstream artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525034/jenkis-downstream-job-fails-to-find-upstream-artifacts) stackoverflow question. I hope this answers your question.